# I want to use a large background image in an game, where the background moves and character remains constant, what file format to use for the image?

Tags: image

Platform I am using is java applet, and I want to know whether I should use jpg, gif, png

jpg tends to slow down the game, 
gif flickers too much
do not have much hope with png in speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One large image is generally a bad idea for performance and memory consumption.
You want to split it in smaller chunks and load/unload them when not in use.

In java2D I always used PNG.
In other libraries it may not be important since they convert the image format to something more GPU friendly.

On the other hand, bmp is the faster thing to load (you don't need to process -i.e. decompress- the image), but it may increase your overall game size.